# Upload and crop image and add text from frontend in wordpress

Tags: image, text, crop

My client needs for his visitors to be able to upload, zoom and crop an image, add text over the cropped image and choose a position of the text.
Something like example on this image: http://devadesign.biz/example.jpg
After clicking on submit button the cropped image, with text on it, has to be saved in a specific folder.
Is there any plugin or tutorial for something like that?

I've already tried some plugins and scripts like those:
https://artisansweb.net/upload-crop-resize-image-using-jquery-php/
https://www.sanwebe.com/2012/05/ajax-image-upload-and-resize-with-jquery-and-php
https://www.sitepoint.com/crop-and-resize-images-with-imagemagick/
http://www.croppic.net/
https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/
...but none of them supports adding text.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in Imagemagick. Here is an example:

Input:

[image]

```
line 1: read input and put into memory and delete input
line 2: add contast to memory input
line 3-5: add white to memory input
line 6-7: create a white image with a black rectangle in the middle as a mask
line 8: composite the two modified input images using the mask
line 9: set up the fill and stroke for creating a black outline around the middle
line 10: draw the black polygon rectangle
line 11: set up the pointsize and colors for the text
line 12: draw the text with annotate
line 13: save the output

convert lena.jpg -write mpr:img +delete \
\( mpr:img -level 10x100% \) \
\( mpr:img -alpha set \
-channel a -evaluate set 80% +channel \
-background white -flatten \) \
\( -clone 0 -fill white -colorize 100 \
-fill black -draw "rectangle 64,64 192,192" -alpha off \) \
-compose over -composite \
-fill none -stroke black \
-draw "polygon 64,64 192,64 192,192 64,192" -alpha off \
-gravity center -pointsize 24 -fill white -stroke white \
-annotate +0+0 "TESTING" \
result.png
```

[image]

For drawing options see https://imagemagick.org/Usage/draw

Wordpress has an Imagemagick plugin. See https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/imagemagick/